# Compile-like validation for EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

I need to make sure the properties I use in JSP page exist. I use 3-rd party jar that I get data from and I want to make sure if some of the data is removed from the objects in that jar that I don't display the bean properties that don't exist.

As I understand reflection is used in EL, so pre-compilation of JSP pages doesn't help. Is there some kind of tool or other solution that can check all the EL properties I use to make sure they exist?

Comment: Depends on IDE. Some has builtin facilities, other has none. What IDE are you using?

Comment: No IDE, I am using text editor. I have Eclipse installed, so I could probably set the project up, but didn't bother yet to import all the dependencies, jars, etc.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA will highlight any EL variable that is not defined and let you specify EL variables that are made available at runtime, as well. I would expect that Eclipse has a similar feature.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out [Eclipse Editor JSP Plugin](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-11.html)

Comment: As I said in comments I don't have and IDE, so Eclipse plugin wouldn't work

Comment: @Romario - To be fair, in your comments you do say "I have Eclipse installed", did you try Eclipse + a plug in?